Why is my video element not playing its track
I'm using Nextjs with Socket.io and Mediasoup to try and (initially) create a p2p video chat.
I've followed a long YouTube video showing me how to get started.
I've got to the stage where I'm receiving the track but it's not playing in the video element.
I've asked ChatGPT to help, but it was no use.
I've logged out track.enabled and it's true.
I've logged out track.readyState and it's live.
I've enabled controls on the recipient video element and when I manually click play (when it has the track) it just loads forever... To no avail.
Here's the useEffect where I try to set the video source:
useEffect(() => {
    if (!consumer) return;

    const { track } = consumer;

    console.log("Consumer received");
    console.log(
      `Track enabled: ${track.enabled}, Track readyState: ${track.readyState}`
    );

    if (!remoteVideoRef.current) {
      console.log("No remote video ref available");
      return;
    }

    // Ensure the video element is ready and track is attached
    try {
      remoteVideoRef.current.srcObject = new MediaStream([track]);
      console.log("MediaStream assigned to video element");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error setting MediaStream:", error);
    }

    // Resume the consumer if necessary
    socket.emit("consumer-resume");
  }, [consumer]);

